# How to solve problem protocol error (IO.read): Read failed with PM2 and puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, pm2

I've this simple code in `index.js`

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.pdf({ path: './prints/test.pdf', format: 'A4' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

It works with command node index.js.
BUT when I want to run it with `pm2`
with cmd `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env=production`
`ecosystem.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "print_ca",
      script: "index.js",
      evn: {
        NODE_ENV: "development",
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
      },
      instances: 1,
      exec_mode: "fork",
      ignore_watch: ["node_modules", "prints", "storage"],
    },
  ],
};
```

But shows the error:
[image]

I don't know why it happens, with `node index.js` it works but with `PM2` won't work?

Comment: Can you provide line #16 of your script `test.js`

Comment: Also, you have a typo in you ecosystem file. Please repalce `evn` by `env`

Comment: Please no images of errors: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

The user's right to start the pm2 process is not enough to access the feature file. try to restart the pm2 in service with the admin account